# Facebook feeds - Limit the amount returned

Tags: json, facebook, rss

I'm using the link https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id= to return a JSON object of the newest updates on a Facebook page. I'm only interested in the newest update. Is there a way I can only retrieve the newest one without retrieving the N older ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're better using the [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) object on the Graph API to pull this kind of data.

If you want posts just by the page itself, then you want

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/posts?limit=1&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE

If you want the latest post, either by the page OR a fan, then you want

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?limit=1&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE

Comment: Looked into this, but I want feeds for a FB group and if I want to generate an access token, FB gives me an error saying I can't generate a token for this group, I have to log in with my own details. So I login with my own details, but the the updates are from my wall and not the group's wall. Tried everything, but it seems getting an access token for a group is impossible.

Comment: Oh, ok, well a group is a whole different approach.

You're right in saying that you can't get a group `access_token`, but if the group isn't public, you'll need an access token for a user that's a member.

There's some more detail on this page - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/